# How to start WAS liberty profile server in remote debug mode.

Tags: remote-debugging, websphere-liberty

I need to start my liberty profile in remote debug mode. Want to know if that is possible? If yes need pointers on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 7):

```
server debug [servername]
```

This will start the server in the foreground in debug mode. You can then connect a debugger to the debug port (default: 7777). There're more details on the options for the server command in the [Knowledge Centre](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_script.html?lang=en).

Alternatively, if you're using WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse, you can  right-click on the server in the servers view and select Debug which will start the server in debug mode and attach the eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebSphere Developer Tools for Eclipse to debug applications on remote servers. Create the remote server and select the "Enable the server to start remotely" option in the server wizard so that you can then restart the remote server in debug mode.

For instructions on how to set up a remote server in WDT see http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/t_creating_remote_server.html

Here's a doc about debugging apps on a server as well
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/tdebug.htm?lang=en